# How to do the print range or worksheet in the excel add-in?

Tags: office365api, excel-addins

I generate tables for the corresponding styles based on the data in the sheet. I want to print them out.

I tried to find the api in the document,but I did not find it.

I would like to know if there is a print function of the api exists, if there is, please give me a help, if not, I think it would be useful to add this api in office-js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "Print" API (partially because the APIs -- at least, until now -- have largely focused on cross-platform APIs, and also because printing is different across the different devices).

That said, please add your suggestion to https://officespdev.uservoice.com/.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,I will submit my proposal,and hope office-js more perfect